# Why are my types not marked as equal?

Tags: c#, reflection, types, interface

There are a few other questions concerning this on SO, but I felt none of them really provided a solid answer.

I'm messing around with reflection a lot lately, and I wanted to check for types contained within a few assemblies that implement a certain interface.

So I have a class called BESCollector that implements ICollector

```
public class BESCollector : ICollector
{
  // ...
}
```

Here I load the assembly, loop through all types and see if that type contains an interface of type ICollector...

```
Assembly pluginAssembly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(pluginConfig.AssemblyLocation);
IEnumerable<Type> types = pluginAssembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(ICollector)));
```

... which yields no results :(. While debugging I can clearly see that it DOES contain this type. I break on the if-loop

```
Assembly pluginAssembly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(pluginConfig.AssemblyLocation);
IEnumerable<Type> types = pluginAssembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(ICollector)));
foreach (Type type in pluginAssembly.GetTypes())
{
    Type[] interfaces = type.GetInterfaces();
    if (interfaces.Contains(typeof(ICollector)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(@"\o/");
    }
}
```

These results are straight from the debugger. Here you can see that `interfaces` contains a single Type, namely ICollector:

```
-       interfaces  {System.Type[1]}    System.Type[]
  +     [0] {Name = "ICollector" FullName = "SquidReports.DataCollector.Interface.ICollector"}  System.Type {System.ReflectionOnlyType}
```

And the Type I'm calling `.GetInterfaces()` on is clearly BESCollector:

```
+       type    {Name = "BESCollector" FullName = "SquidReports.DataCollector.Plugin.BES.BESCollector"} System.Type {System.ReflectionOnlyType}
```

But the equality statement `interfaces.Contains(typeof(ICollector))` never evaluates to true.

Just so you think I'm not mixing up types here, when I mouse over `(typeof(ICollector))` while debugging, it clearly displays `SquidReports.DataCollector.Interface.ICollector`.

This, of course, does work:

```
Type[] interfaces = type.GetInterfaces();
if (interfaces.Any(t => t.Name == typeof(ICollector).Name))
{
    Console.WriteLine(@"\o/");
}
```

But that does't tell me a whole lot, besides the fact that the types of the same name.

Moreover, why does this check fail?

```
if (typeof(ICollector).Equals(typeof(ICollector)))
{
    Console.WriteLine("EQUALIZED");
}
```

Why does my first equality check fail? More specifically, how does type equality work in C# 5.0? Was there nothing specific implemented for .Equals() for the 'Type' type?

**EDIT:**

At the request of I Quality Catalyst below quickly did a test if the equality would evaluate to true if the interface and class were defined in the same assembly. This DOES work:

```
class Program
{
    public interface ITest
    {

    }

    public class Test : ITest
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Type[] interfaces = (typeof(Test)).GetInterfaces();
        if (interfaces.Any(t => t == typeof(ITest)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(@"\o/");
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT2**: Here's the implementation of ICollector

```
public interface ICollector
{
    IDbRelay DbRelay { get; set; }
    ILogManager LogManager { get; set; }

    void Init(ILogManager logManager, IDbRelay dbRelay);
    void Execute();
}
```

However, I do believe I may have missed out on an important detail. I'm working with three Assemblies here:

1. The 'Main' (`SquidReports.DataCollector`) assembly where I'm doing the equality check
2. The 'Interface' (`SquidReports.DataCollector.Interface`) assembly that contains ICollector
3. The 'Plugin' (`SquidReports.DataCollector.Plugin.BES`) assembly that contains the definition of BESCollector

It is probably very important to note that the 'Interface' (`SquidReports.DataCollector.Interface`) is being loaded from the ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve event, like shown below, because ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom() does not automatically resolves dependencies:

```
public Assembly ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    // This event is used to resolve dependency problems. We need to return the requested assembly in this method.
    // We should probably look in two locations:
    //   1. The SquidReports.DataCollector folder
    //   2. The Corresponding folder in SquidReports.DataCollector\Plugins    

    // Let's first turn the 'full' assembly name into something more compact
    AssemblyName assemblyName = new AssemblyName(args.Name);
    this.Logger.LogMessage(LogLevel.Debug, String.Format("Attempting to resolve Assembly {0} to load {0}", assemblyName.Name, args.RequestingAssembly.GetName().Name));

    // Let's also get the location where the requesting assembly is located
    DirectoryInfo pluginDirectory = Directory.GetParent(args.RequestingAssembly.Location);
    string assemblyFileName = String.Format("{0}.dll", assemblyName.Name);

    if (File.Exists(assemblyFileName))
    {
        // It's in the main bin folder, let's try to load from here
        return Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(assemblyFileName);
    }
    else if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(pluginDirectory.FullName, assemblyFileName)))
    {
        // It's in the plugin folder, let's load from there
        return Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(Path.Combine(pluginDirectory.FullName, assemblyFileName));
    }

    return null;
}
```

**EDIT3**: At the suggestion of Joe below, I debugged the application again using this:

```
if (type.Name == "BESCollector")
{
    Type[] interfaces = type.GetInterfaces();
    Type interface1 = interfaces[0];
    Type interface2 = typeof(ICollector);
    Console.WriteLine("");
}
```

I copied the complete properties of `interface1` and `interface2`, then threw those in a file diff.

The result, I think, may have solved my problem:

`interface1` is described as follows:

```
interface1  {Name = "ICollector" FullName = "SquidReports.DataCollector.Interface.ICollector"}  System.Type {System.ReflectionOnlyType}
```

Whereas `interface2` is described like this:

```
interface2  {Name = "ICollector" FullName = "SquidReports.DataCollector.Interface.ICollector"}  System.Type {System.RuntimeType}
```

So am I correct in assuming that the problem is caused because {System.RuntimeType} != {System.ReflectionOnlyType}, and that Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom() is to blame for this?

Comment: Does your equality check work with any other interface which is defined in the same assembly?

Comment: @Quality Catalyst: Well actually that DOES seem to work, see my update above. I don't quite follow here.

Comment: Can you also show us the declaration of `ICollector' please?

Comment: @RobinMattheussen is the Deriving class in the same assembly as the interface?

Comment: Can you also post the value of this: `pluginConfig.AssemblyLocation`

Comment: @Dev No problem, here: "C:\\Source\\C#\\SquidReports\\SquidReports.DataCollector\\bin\\x86\\Debug\\Plugins\\SquidResport.DataCollector.Plugin.BES\\SquidReports.DataCollector.Plugin.BES.dll"

Comment: It would be interesting to compare the properties (public and private), of the type returned by typeof(ICollection) and the type contained in the interfaces[] returned by GetInterfaces().

Comment: I would hazard a guess to say that is correct, but I'd have to do a little research to verify.

Comment: It would be interesting to see if IsAssignableFrom worked or not as well.

Comment: @Joe, it did not unfortunately :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72538/discussion-between-joe-enzminger-and-robin-mattheussen).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I stumbled upon the answer thanks to Joe Enzminger:

It would appear that, because I was using `Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom()`, the Type that I was loading from the Assembly was actually a System.ReflectionOnlyType as opposed to a System.RuntimeType.

Basically, there is one simple and one pretty cool solution for this:

1. Stop using `ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom()` and switch to LoadFrom(). This solves all your problemes. Unless of course you're using ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom for a very good reason.
2. In that case, you can simply use Type.GUID. Regardless of the context from which the type was loaded, the GUIDs will be the same. So you can simple do

   if ((typeof(MyReflectionType)).GUID == (typeof(MyType)).GUID)
   {
     // Blah ...
   }

That should solve your problems :)

Comment: Good idea comparing GUIDs.